# PPG tables online?

Tags: wort

Does anybody know if a table of ppg for various common ingredients can be found online somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

I like to reference the tables from [Beersmith](http://www.beersmith.com/Grains/Grains/GrainList.htm) and [Homebrewtalk](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/wiki/index.php/Malts_Chart).  The homebrewtalk chart is especially nice with the added characteristics and the Beersmith chart has the max in batch column which is nice to reference when checking your grist percentages.

The How to Brew chart that baka posted is nice in that it provides some steeping ppg for specialty grains not just mash ppg but their aren't very many on there.

Answer (score 1):

Here's [one from How To Brew](http://www.howtobrew.com/section2/chapter12-4-1.html)